# Can we setup the integral as this?

Tags: integration

${\dfrac{d}{dx}\Large\int} _{0}^{sinx} x^2\sqrt t\ \ dt$
as

${\dfrac{d}{dx}\ x^2 \Large\int} _{0}^{sinx} \sqrt t\ \ dt$

if so can i do the same thing for this too but I will endup with dt

${\dfrac{d}{dx}\Large\int} _{x}^{\sqrt x} \dfrac{e^x}{x}\ dt$

here all the variables are x except the dt can we pull out the $\dfrac{e^x}{x}$

${\dfrac{d}{dx}\dfrac{e^x}{x}\Large\int} _{x}^{\sqrt x} \ dt$

what can I do with ${\Large\int} _{x}^{\sqrt x} \ dt$?

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: Definetly, $x^2$ *works* exactly like a constant when you integrate wrt t, even if the bounds contains a function of $x$, that doesn't afect the $x^2$.

Comment: Thanks @Clayton

Comment: Got it. Thanks@Zacky

Comment: Yes, anything that doesn't depend on $t$ can be treated as a constant and pulled out of the integral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$dt$ is there to tell you with respect to what variable you're integrating. In your case, the variable of integration is $t$. Anything that's not $t$ is considered a constant (it's a number, in other words) that you can pull in and out of the integral sign. This is one of the most basic properties of both indefinite and definite integrals:

$$
\int af(x)\,dx=a\int f(x)\,dx
$$

If it's $dt$, then it tells you that the variable of integration is $t$ and all other variables that are not $t$ are constants which means that they can be pulled out front. If it's $dx$, the variable of integration is $x$ and all other variables that are not $x$ are constants which, again, can be pulled out front. If it's $dy$, then your variable of integration is going to be $y$ and all other variables are considered constants and, sure enough, can be brought out of the integral sign. Long story short, $dX$ tells you that $X$ is the variable of integration which means you can't pull expressions containing $X$ out of the integral sign. Anything else, you can.

Take a look at this example:

$$
\int_{x}^{\sqrt{x}}x\,dt=x\int_{x}^{\sqrt{x}}\,dt=x\cdot t\bigg|_{x}^{\sqrt{x}}=x\left(\sqrt{x}-x\right)=x\sqrt{x}-x^2.
$$

Comment: Yup but I have dt but I don't have any variable to integrate

Comment: Do you mean like, $f(t)=1$?

Comment: yes, I got it now. Thanks